# how to verify the SVG icons using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to validate the SVG icon for a drop down list items SVG icon. Each items having unique SVG icon. How can i validate the SVG icon using robot framework.

```
<span _ngcontent-c16="" class="flexColumnStatic role" style="height:20px; width: 25px; padding-left:4px;"><!----><mat-icon _ngcontent-c16="" class="roleIcon mat-icon mat-icon-inline" inline="true" role="img" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><defs><path id="__2CNlSzv__editor-a" d="M7,21.2505178 L7,25 L10.7494792,25 L21.8079433,13.9415271 L18.0584641,10.1920448 L7,21.2505178 Z M24.7075406,11.0419275 C25.0974865,10.6519813 25.0974865,10.0220683 24.7075406,9.63212214 L22.3678656,7.29244522 C22.18106,7.1052184 21.9274444,7 21.6629635,7 C21.3984826,7 21.144867,7.1052184 20.9580614,7.29244522 L19.1283155,9.12219255 L22.8777948,12.8716748 L24.7075406,11.0419275 Z"></path></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-7 -7)"><rect width="32" height="32"></rect><use fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#__2CNlSzv__editor-a"></use></g></svg></mat-icon></span>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add - what do you mean by validating - their presence, content, rendered shape, or something else; show a sample of your attempts so far, and what's not working for you. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "validate the icon"? Is it good enough to simply check that `<svg...>` element is on the page?

Comment: @BryanOakley can you send a sample code for checking svg

Comment: No, I’ve never done that. Plus, I still don’t know what you mean. What do you mean by “checking the svg”? What sort of check are you wanting to make?